# Firebase js library retrieves empty data from non empty database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

steps to reproduce:

Initialize your firebase db to:

```
{
  "restaurants" : [ {
    "address" : "via Rettifilo, 34 Castelguidone CH Italy",
    "title" : "Dama & Dama"
  }, {
    "address" : "Corso Umberto I, 3 Castelguidone CH Italy",
    "title" : "Bar sabatino"
  } ]
}
```

Check your read/write firebase persmission rules to be

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Execute this js code:

```
firebase.inizializeApp(yourJsonConfig)
\*code*\
firebase.database().ref().once('value').then(function(snapshot){ 
    console.log(snapshot.val()); \\ this will print  Array(0)
})
```

Expected behaviour: console logs `"{'restaurants' ........}"`

Actual behaviour: console logs `"Array(0)"` i.e. NO DATA!

I use firebase js library (version 4.13.1). Where am I wrong?

Comment: Try `console.log(snapshot.val());`.  Example in [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val).

Comment: I have tried that, but without success

Answer (score 1):

You need use val() method to return your data.

```
 firebase.database().ref().once('value').then(function(snapshot){ 
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

**Edit**: Then your problem exist in another piece of code what you did not show.

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zgfr91yd/

In console log:

[image]

And see my data:

[image]

You need a unique key for parent of each restaurant. You can use 'push' function in Firebase for that.

Comment: This won't change anything :(

Comment: @SimoneMSR check my new edit for a complete example of your question.

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot` argument that's being passed to your callback is an object of type [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).  You shouldn't assume that the JSON formatting string of a DataSnapshot contains just the data from that location in the database.  As you can see from the API docs, there are a lot of methods functionality in a DataSnapshot.

What you what to do is call [val()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val) on that snapshot in order to extract a JavaScript value from it.  Read the API docs to further understand what that object may contain.

Comment: I see your point (and I have updated the question), but the val() methods returns `[]`